# What's the name of the transformation from a matrix $M$ to $A M A^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis, similar-matrices

Suppose I have a square matrix $M$. If $P$ is another square, invertible matrix, then $PMP^{-1}$ is said to be *similar* to $M$.

Now consider a transformation of the form $AMA^T$, where $A$ can be rectangular. Is there a name for this kind of transformation?

If $A$ is square and orthogonal, then we are back to the previous case because $A^T = A^{-1}$. My question is about the general case, where $A$ is not orthogonal, it need not be invertible, and can even be rectangular.

Comment: For non-orthogonal, square invertible $A$, it is called [matrix congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence). (I do not know if the terminology extends to non-invertible or rectangular $A$.)

Comment: @nejimban Thanks. Do you know what happens to the eigenvectors after such a transform?

Comment: Would also be interested if A is rectangular with maximal rank. Could we add the prefix ''sub-''

Comment: @nejimban in the case of a square, invertible $A$, I confirm that it is called matrix congruence and in the case that $M$ is symmetric (or Hermitian in the complex case), $AMA^T$ and $M$ have the same number of positive and negative eigenvalues. This is the subject of Sylvester's law of inertia.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If you do a [Singular Value Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of $A$
$$
A = U\Sigma V^T \quad A^T  = V\Sigma ^T U^T 
$$
then you get
$$
AMA^T  = U\Sigma V^T MV\Sigma ^T U^T 
$$
and if A is square ...

Or you can do a [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) ...

Comment: I don't understand where you want to get?